# Send single item Image path "onItemClick" when parsing json file in Android

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-volley

I was following this tutorial [android custom listview with image and text using volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) (original project files can be found [here](https://github.com/Belbola/android-images-listView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/laxo/lofaif/imageslistview)) and I have modified the code to display more information about a single item when the user clicks on an item.

here is partial content of `MainActivity.java`

```
....
// Parsing json
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
  try {
       movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
       // this is the image path in the json file     
       movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));

......
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String _movieTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MoreInfoActivity.class);
    // send movie title
    myIntent.putExtra("title", _movieTitle) ;
    // the problem is here, I cannot send the image path            
    //myIntent.putExtra("image", R.id.image) ;
    startActivity(myIntent) ;
  }
});
```

`custom adapter` contents:

```
if (imageLoader == null)
    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

// getting movie data for the row
Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

// thumbnail image
thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
```

my `moredetailsactivity.java`:

```
public class moredetailsactivity extends Activity {
    private TextView title, image;
    private String _title,_rating,_image;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_details);
        title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        image = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    if (i.getExtras() != null) {
       _title = (String) i.getExtras().get("title");
       _image = (String) i.getExtras().get("image");
    }
    title.setText(_title);
    .....
  }
```

I want to display the same thumbnail which is in the `mainactivity` in the `moredetailsactivity`.

this shows image in the `main_activity.xml`

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

but the same code does not show anything on `more_details.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private JSONArray movieList;
    .......

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String _movieTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MoreInfoActivity.class);

            String image = movieList.get(position).getString("image");


            // send movie title
            myIntent.putExtra("title", _movieTitle) ;
            myIntent.putExtra("image", _movieTitle) ;

            // the problem is here, I cannot send the image path            
            //myIntent.putExtra("image", R.id.image) ;
            startActivity(myIntent) ;
          }
        });
```

Comment: I get this error `error: cannot find symbol method getString(String)` here is the full [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/z7KYXHi6)